# Nuget package installation failure

Tags: .net, nuget

When trying to install a package from our newly created private Nuget Feed i get the following error.

Could not install package 'GC.Timecode 1.0.0.3'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.

The Nuget package also targets 4.5.1. (Screenshot take from Nuget Package Explorer)

The Nuget Package is created by Octopack via On premises TFS, and then published to a private Proget Server

[image]

Nuspec file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
<metadata>
<id>GC.Timecode</id>
<version>1.0.0.3</version>
<authors>user</authors>
<owners>user</owners>
<licenseUrl>http://example.com</licenseUrl>
<projectUrl>http://example.com</projectUrl>
<requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
<description>The GC.Timecode deployment package, built on 25/01/2016</description>
<releaseNotes />
</metadata>
</package>
```

Contents of Package

[image]

What's going on here?

Comment: How did you obtain that screenshot, is that from the NuGet Package Explorer if you inspect the `lib\net45\assemblyname.dll` assembly? Does the package work when not used through your feed, but for example from the filesystem? Does it work on other machines? What does the .NuSpec look like? What _are_ the contents of the package? What feed software do you use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was that Octopack will by default just replicate the existing folder structure, whereas Nuget will package your dll into a lib folder.

For the lazy, you can use this package in order to Get a nuget package built on every build

https://www.nuget.org/packages/CreateNewNuGetPackageFromProjectAfterEachBuild/

Comment: I will, in 2 days when SO will let me :)

Comment: This package is amazing, you'd be crazy to do it any other way. THANKS!

Answer (score 24):

Slippery Pete fixed this problem for me.

The first time I tried to install my Assembly I got:

> Could not install package 'Package Name'. You are trying to install this >package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1', but the >package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are >compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package >author.

After ensuring my Assembly within the Nuget package was in the 'lib\net45' folder, I still got the error!

However after going to Tools->Options->Nuget->General and clearing the cache, the problem was solved.

Comment: I had this same problem.  You can also clear the Nuget cache through the package manager console with this command:
nuget locals all -list

Comment: Huh? All I see with `Tools > Options` with "NuGet" is `NuGet Package Manager`, then `General` as described but then just 3 options: to allow download of missing pkgs, auto-check for them during builds, and to skip applying binding redirects. Nothing about clearing cache.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2017 Pro there is a [Clear All NuGet Cache(s)] button on the General page.

Answer (score 14):

Make sure your nuspec file contains a 'lib/net45' target

```
<package>
  <metadata>
    ...
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="bin\Release\*.*" target="lib/net45" />
  </files>
</package>
```

Answer (score 14):

This happened to me and I didn't find my solution posted to any of these sites, so hopefully this helps someone else.

The message I was getting was:

> Could not install package 'Package Name'. You are trying to install
>   this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.

I had a Nuget package that was built for all 4.x versions so it shouldn't matter that it didn't specify version 4.6.1 specifically.  I tried changing the class library build to 4.0, 4.5, 4.5.2, 4.6, 4.6.1, and 4.6.2 but nothing fixed this problem.  I also added multiple versions of the DLL to the package in individual /lib/Net4(5,51,52,6,61,62) folders and the error was still there.

Eventually, I found out the reason for my problem was the initial private Nuget package I created was a "bad" package and that bad package was cached to my local machine.

I fixed the package problem and pushed the new package to our Nuget server (leaving the version name the same), but Nuget inside Visual Studio wasn't pulling down the new package but instead referenced the bad package cached on my local machine at.  Package Manager showed the package was updated and displayed the information correctly from our Nuget server but it was never fetching the new package.  It was always retrieving the cached package at:

C:\Users\your_user_account\.Nuget\packages\

Simply deleting the package in question under your local user account forced Package Manager to pull down the new package from the server.

Answer (score 4):

I was also getting the following message.

> Could not install package 'Package Name'. You are trying to install
>   this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.

In my case, [changing the package management format from packages.config to PackageReference](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference/) solved the problem.

Comment: THANKS! I was having a problem installing `Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI` in order to use `DelegateCommand` and changing package.config to packagereference helped to solve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility which I just worked through was that **local Nuget tools can be too old**.

I was trying to install https://github.com/alastairtree/LazyCache which is a .Net standard 2.0 project. My local project was .NET framework 4.7.2, which *is* compatible. And yet I got the error cited in the question.

The problem was that my VS2015 installation of Nuget was not the latest. Although under Tools > Extensions *it did NOT show any available updates*, there was in fact a much newer Nuget available at https://www.nuget.org/downloads (3.6x vs 3.4x I believe).

I installed that and the problem was resolved. Apparently the old Nuget did not understand what .NET Standard was.

Comment: How did you installed ?

Comment: @MuhammadAli Starting in Visual Studio 2017, the installer includes the NuGet Package Manager. For 2015 or earlier, see https://www.nuget.org/downloads which has downloads for 2015 and 2013

Comment: Yeah I have VS2017 installed, But you said I installed new version because VS have old version of nuget installed. So how do you install nuget ? In the downloads I just see an console exe. What to do with that exe ? Please can you explain more ?

Comment: @MuhammadAli In my case it was 2015. Direct link to the EXE is: https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe .  ALso, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47497456/3195477

Comment: Ok that's fine, I have nuget.exe. So how do I make VS to use nuget.exe OR how I do install package using nuget.exe ?

Comment: I am not sure for 2017, I only had to solve this for 2015. 2017 should let you update the VSIX package pointed out on the link above..?  If not, post a new question for that.

Comment: Hi I solved it, I was having wrong package like Mono.Android version v8.0 and I was using 6.

Comment: @MuhammadAli glad you worked it out. Always a good feeling to solve a problem like that :)

Comment: Yeah I have great happy feelings after solving that, Thanks for your corporation brother !

Answer (score 2):

If you're using nuspec make sure that all installed packages are noted as "dependencies" in the metadata.

```
<dependencies>
      <dependency id="MyIncludedPackage" version="1.13.0" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
```

Adding all the packages solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think solution may vary from case to case, however, in my case, NuGet package was built/compiled in "Class Library .NET Core 3.1" whilst the project which were using this package belonged to .NET Framework. I just changed the project type to .NET Core 3.1 and added NuGet package again and it worked for me.