# Server not found after external login MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin

Hello I use the code from https://coding.abel.nu/2014/11/using-owin-external-login-without-asp-net-identity/

and I was getting the error "The page isn't redirecting properly". after I login to my provider.

I clear my cookies but now when I log in to my provider but I get "Server not found". "Firefox can't find the server at login;jsessionid=f09ba421eeee23eab2a1ffa8b6ed35c3." in the url it returns https://login;jsessionid=f09ba421eeee23eab2a1ffa8b6ed35c3/. My provider is CAS. This is for firefox. In chrome it just brings a blank page.

I try it also with Google but I get same errors.

Any idea?
thank you

Answer (score 1):

I believe I had the similar bug, there was one line solution to this bug...

"here is a bug in Microsoft's Owin implementation for System.Web. The one that is being used when running Owin applications on IIS. Which is what probably 99% of us do, if we're using the new Owin-based authentication handling with ASP.NET MVC5.

The bug makes cookies set by Owin mysteriously disappear on some occasions..."

solution here: https://github.com/KentorIT/owin-cookie-saver

Comment: Hello thank you for your reply. I try to install the package but I get the error "Could not install package 'Kentor.OwinCookieSaver 1.1.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1', but the package does not conta
in any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. " Do I need another version?

Comment: Same error from there. I installed previous version but no change. I get Server not found.

Comment: I found this solution: you can use this package in order to Get a nuget package built on every build
original post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34991703/nuget-package-installation-failure

Comment: Did you add this line: app.UseKentorOwinCookieSaver(); before app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()); ?

Comment: In some cases, a pipeline stage specification might be needed: app.UseKentorOwinCookieSaver(PipelineStage.Authenticate); did you try with that?

Comment: Nothing...do you believed?? The strange thing is that I have another app which use identity and returns ok to my website.

Comment: Finally your solution, was right for Google, so I upvoted. For CAS I had to add some more classes like Authentication Middleware and some more.  thank you

Comment: Thank you very much, glad you figured it out!