# Where is Nuget 4 installed

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2017

Visual Studio 2017 comes with Nuget 4.0.0. However, it's not placed on the path. Where can I find the nuget executable to use the CLI?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Visual Studio 2017** doesn't use `NuGet.exe` but instead uses an extension of **NuGet** to achieve this. You should be able to find the extension in this path:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\`*`<VSEdition>`*`\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet`

... where *`<VSEdition>`* is the version of Visual Studio being used, for example `Community` or `Enterprise`.

If you want to use the CLI, you'll have to download it separately. Here is a [link explaining the same](http://www.visualstudioresources.com/2017/10/04/how-to-get-the-location-of-nuget-exe-used-by-visual-studio/).

Comment: there are many nuget dll files, but NO nuget.exe using 2017 Pro latest