# Could not install package 'NuGet.Server 2.11.3' VS 2015

Tags: .net, nuget

My requirement is to write a NuGet server. Following this tutorial here:
http://nugetserver.net/

I get the following error every time:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>       Error       Could not install package 'NuGet.Server 2.11.3'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

After having checked my project's properties, my target .NET framework is 4.5.2 - please refer to screenshot: [image]

I had a look at this SO post: [Nuget package installation failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34991703/nuget-package-installation-failure) but still no luck. I am using VS 2015.

This is as much information as I give in order to try reproduce the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to update your Target framework to .NETFramework 4.6 or higher.

See the dependencies at https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Server/

Comment: What an easy fix.. Wow after wasting the whole of yesterday on this. Thank you @Niels . And By the way I had already had .NET Framework 4.6 installed. I think it was just a matter of understanding the error properly. Thank you for your valued effort.