# Native NuGet package installation failure

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2017, nuget

I created two NuGet packages: a native (C++) NuGet package and a regular .NET NuGet  package that depends on the former one; and deployed both to an in-house NuGet repo.
Then I created a test .NET project and **successfully installed** the lead .NET package, while PM installs the native package as well.

Next, I tried to install the .NET package into an actual consumer .NET project, and **the installation failed** with the error message:

> Could not install package 'Native 1.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.

Both projects (test/successful and product/unsuccessful) indeed target *.NET v4.7.1*, both target *AnyCPU* and both use the same toolset.

```xml
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

I am out off ideas why installation of my package produces the above error in the product project.
Thank you all in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi friend, what's the result if you clean the nuget package by [Package Manager UI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43653975/10910450) It seems you used different way to consume the packages in two projects. Please make sure both the projects are `PackageReference format` , and then consume the packages all by UI. I think after that the results could be the same, all install successfully or all failed. And then share more details if it failed.

Comment: You say that both projects target .NET 4.7.2, so I assume the C++ project is still .NET, and not a native win32 dll that needs to be P/Invoked from the other .NET library. When you open the nupkg as a zip file, are the dlls in the `lib/net472` folder?

Comment: @zivkan When I say both projects target _.NET v4.7.1_, I refer to two consuming projects: first - test/successful, second - product/unsuccessful. 
The native project is a pure C++ project that does not target .NET.

Comment: In that case, the native package can't be packed in the same way that .net assemblies are packed and that's almost certainly why you're getting the error. If you only want to support SDK style projects (used by, but not limited to, .NET Core), then have a look at the layout of the `libuv` package. Otherwise to support all (.NET) consuming project types, you need to provide your own props and targets files. Look how the `System.Data.SQLite.Core` package does it for an example.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT It was it 
In a production project _packages.config_ was still in use. I converted it to the _PackageReference_ format, and the native package was consumed like a charm.
Unfortunately, I cannot mark a comment as an answer, so please do add an answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then I created a test .NET project and successfully installed the lead
> .NET package, while PM installs the native package as well.
>
> Next, I tried to install the .NET package into an actual consumer .NET
> project, and the installation failed with the error message:

There's many workarounds for this kind of messgae `the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework` online. For your specific issue, since one succeeds, the other not:

1. I suggest `clean the nuget cache` first, then do other checks. Cause when you install or restore nuget pakcages, it will firstly try to find it in cache. Similar issue see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43653975/10910450).
2. Then make sure all your projects in same solution use same way to manage nuget packages. (All PackageReference or all packages.config). And for VS217 and higher, packageReference is more recommended:) Similar issue see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56786197/10910450).